# mvc4 model defines and how to return it as List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class resultInfo
    {
        public String result { get; set; }
        public String errorCode { get; set; }
        public String exceptionMsg { get; set; }
        public String message { get; set; }
        public String jobType { get; set; }
        public String menuId { get; set; }        
    }
```

This is a model for controller's process result. I'm gonna use this throughout the whole controllers.

Sometimes I could just set only 'result' value or sometimes set two or more values on the items.

and I want it to be a list, so that I can give the result information to the client in JSON object.

I know how to convert List object to Json, but don't know how to make the model List object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like any other model..

At the top of your view just declare it as `@model List<resultInfo>` and pass your list from the controller

Then in your view you have the @Model property with a reference to your list model.